# Single column into two with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to work out how to write a Macro to replace the current Excel formula I'm using. I've tried experimenting with cell values and offsets but my knowledge of VBA is minimal. What I need it to do is to turn a single column list like this:

Cell 1

Cell 2

Cell 3

Cell 4

Cell 5

Cell 6

Into a two-column list like this:

Cell 1 Cell 2

Cell 3 Cell 4

Cell 5 Cell 6

I feel as if it should be pretty simple to achieve, but I want to avoid blank spaces and a loop will probably be required as the length of the list is likely to change each time the macro is run. Can anybody help?

Comment: do you have to use a macro for this? you can do it in a few steps with regular formulas

Comment: I was using formulas to do it before but was worried they'd be deleted by other users. I've come up with a solution now anyway. Thanks in any case for replying.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work out how to do it:

```
Sub splitColumn()
Range("A1").Select
Do
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1)) Then
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value = ActiveCell
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try with the following code:
But its a bit too long...I think it may help you in providing some ideas...

```
Sub Splitting()
Dim i, j, k, l As Integer
RowCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To RowCount Step 2
For j = 1 To 1
Cells(i, j + 1).Value = Cells(i, j).Value
Cells(i, j + 2).Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value
Next j
Next i
Call Removeblanks
End Sub

Sub Removeblanks()
RowCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To RowCount
For j = 1 To 1
If (Cells(i, j + 1).Value = "") Then
Cells(i, j + 1).Delete
Cells(i, j + 2).Delete
End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```